# Cannot mix incompatible Qt library (5.14.2) with this library (5.15.1) in debian bullseye

Tags: debian, qt

I can't launch any program that uses Qt since I copied some gl.so manually and/or updated debian bullseye... I don't know.

```
user@desktop:~$ vlc
VLC media player 3.0.11.1 Vetinari (revision 3.0.11.1-0-g52483f3ca2)
[0000562b1d36d5b0] main libvlc: Running vlc with the default interface. Use 'cvlc' to use vlc without interface.
Cannot mix incompatible Qt library (5.14.2) with this library (5.15.1)
Aborted

root@desktop:~# sudo ldconfig -p | grep -i gl.so
    libwayland-egl.so.1 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwayland-egl.so.1
    libobs-opengl.so.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libobs-opengl.so.0
    libcogl.so.20 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcogl.so.20
    libQt5OpenGL.so.5 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5OpenGL.so.5
    libOpenGL.so.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libOpenGL.so.0
    libOpenGL.so.0 (libc6) => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libOpenGL.so.0
    libGL.so.1 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1
    libGL.so.1 (libc6) => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1
    libEGL.so.1 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libEGL.so.1
    libEGL.so.1 (libc6) => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libEGL.so.1
    libCgl.so.1 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libCgl.so.1
```

I tried reinstalling Qt, but it doesnt work, please help I can't run many programs.

I checked bash_history and only find this, but I remember I copied other libraries to /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ folder:

```
sudo cp /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/
```

**What should I do now? I Tried reinstalling Qt5 but it doesn't work.**
Thank you.

EDIT: I restored to a previous state with timeshift (it's a life saver).
I don't need anymore this post, but I think may be usseful for debian users to be answered cos I only found arch related topics with this issue.
I hope I explained myself well enough, English is not my native language.

Comment: what's your question?

Comment: It's hard to help you when you're not sure what exactly you've done to your system to trigger the error.

Comment: I eddited the main question with more info.